# What is this suculent-like plant

Tags: identification, indoors

We inherited this indoor plant with a house in the UK. It seems to be a suculent (but does not seem happy in a warm, dry spot), but there is another similar plant in the house which has its roots submerged in water.

The plant seems to be out-growing its roots at the moment, and is at risk of toppling out of its pot. The stem is roughly 5mm across.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Kalanchoe blossfeldiana - these are usually bought in flower and often discarded after flowering is over, but can be kept as a foliage houseplant ongoing. It is possible to get them to flower again, but usually only after spending aummer outdoors, see here https://www.plantsrescue.com/kalanchoe-blossfeldiana/